# Create new List object in python

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in python. I want to Create new List object in python.

**My Code:**

```
recordList=[]

mappedDictionay={}

sectionGroupName= None

for record in recordCols:
    item = record
    print item

    if not sectionGroupName == record[0]:
        sectionGroupName = record[0]
        del recordList[0:] # Here I want to create new list object for recordList
        recordList.append(item)
        mappedDictionay[sectionGroupName] = recordList
    else:
        recordList.append(tempItem)
```

Comment: Could you show what data structure you're starting with, and what you want to end with? There's more than likely a better way to do what you want but I can't puzzle it out from your example code.

Answer (score 20):

It's not that easy to understand your question, especially since your code lost its formatting, but you can create new list objects quite easily. The following assigns a new list object to the variable recordList:

```
recordList = list()
```

You could also use

```
recordList = []
```

[] and list() are equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Python is [garbage-collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). Just do

```
recordList = []
```

and you'll have a new empty list.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `del`.  Period.  It's an "advanced" thing.

```
from collections import defaultdict

mappedDictionay= defaultdict( list ) # mappedDictionary is a poor name
sectionGroupName= None

for record in recordCols:
    mappedDictionay[record[0]].append( record )
```

Comment: @crk: If it's useful, perhaps you should click accept.  If it's not acceptable, perhaps you should explain what more you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list()` or simply `[]` to create a new list.
However, I think what you are trying to achieve can be solved simply by using `grouby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
mappedIterator = groupby(recordCols, lambda x: x[0])
```

or

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
mappedIterator = groupby(recordCols, itemgetter(0))
```

if you prefer.

The `groupBy` function will return an iterator rather than a dictionary, where each item is of the form `(category, sub-iterator-over-items-in-that-category)`.

If you really want to convert it into a dictionary like you have it in your code, you can run the following afterwards:

```
mappedDictionary = dict(( (x[0], list(x[1])) for x in mappedIterator ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new list?
It's easy: for eg, you wanna make a list of days, write the following:

`new_list=['mon','tue','wed','thurs','fri',sat','sun']`

Here the name of the list is `new_list` and it contains the name of different week days.

**Note**: never forget use [ ] brackets to make a list, using ( ) will create a tuple, a very different object and { } will create a dictionary object which will raise a error instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to create a new list!
If you want it empty, then just define it like this:

```
NameOfList = []
```

or:

```
NameOfList = list()
```